# Common Lisp on CentOS 7

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, redhat, sbcl, centos7

I'm looking for a way to get a working Common Lisp compiler in CentOS 7.

It seems that neither base or EPEL repos contain any of the widely available open-source Lisp compilers. There are bits of info regarding CLISP and SBCL on CentOS 6 but none about any compiler on CentOS 7.

Am I missing something here or has the switch from RHEL6 to RHEL7 completely forgot about CL compilers ?

Answer (score 8):

It's often better to get Common Lisp systems directly than from a distribution's package system. The package system lags behind, and the library model of Common Lisp does not lend itself well to packages.

You can download an SBCL binary from http://www.sbcl.org/

You can get Clozure CL from http://ccl.clozure.com/

Other implementations are available in similar ways, but those two are the best.

Answer (score 2):

I am sure `yum install sbcl clisp` will work:

```
$ yum search sbcl
Failed to set locale, defaulting to C
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, refresh-packagekit, security
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: centos.mirror.nac.net
 * epel: mirrors.einstein.yu.edu
 * extras: reflector.westga.edu
 * updates: mirror.es.its.nyu.edu
========================================== N/S Matched: sbcl 
maxima-runtime-sbcl.x86_64 : Maxima compiled with SBCL
sbcl.x86_64 : Steel Bank Common Lisp

  Name and summary matches only, use "search all" for everything.
```

Comment: It won't.  Neither sbcl or clisp are in the standard CentOS repos.  They're not in EPEL either.

Comment: This is how it should work. Would you know in which repo your sbcl package stands ?

Answer (score 2):

SBCL is available in EPEL7: https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/7/x86_64/repoview/sbcl.html

(I guess it wasn't yet provided when this question was originally asked, but at least at the time of writing this it's there.)

Answer (score 0):

There is a COPR-Repo for EPEL7: https://copr.fedoraproject.org/coprs/shassard/sbcl/

Maybe you like to try this one?

Answer (score 0):

I am able to install SBCL on Amazon EC-2 - CentOS 7 using the following command:

```
wget https://copr-be.cloud.fedoraproject.org/results/shassard/sbcl/epel-7-x86_64/sbcl-1.2.9-1.el7.centos/sbcl-1.2.9-1.el7.centos.x86_64.rpm
sudo rpm -Uvh sbcl-1.2.9-1.el7.centos.x86_64.rpm
```

Note: I wasn't able to run "sudo yum install SBCL"